# Split bootstrap 3 form across tabs

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap page with nothing but just a form in it. Form has some 50 inputs varying from text to select to picture upload options. I am trying to divide the form elements into three categories in three different tabs.

I want only one save button which should be used to save all the information across different tabs in one click.

So far i have been able to come up with following code:

```
<div class="container">
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="row">
            <div>
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#a" data-toggle="tab">Primary Information</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#b" data-toggle="tab">Additional Information</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#c" data-toggle="tab">More Details</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="a">
                            <br/>                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="b">
                            <br/>                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="c">
                            <br/>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <hr/>
                <div class="col-lg-5 pull-right">
                    <div class="">
                        <button id="save" name="save" class="btn btn-primary col-lg-5 pull-right">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

But it's not working. See in the attached image, Primay information tab is supposed to be covering all tab contents but it's not.

[image]

Comment: please add plunker / jsfiddle link